# Set an option in an iframed page

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that has an iframed site in it. It's a service I subscribe to for my customers. Currently I have to end my customers to a site like this myname.serviceisubribeto.com I would prefer to send them to myowndomain.com. So forward or iframe. Iframe let's me add other things to the page for SEO purposes.

So the question I have is can I set an option that the iframed page offers as the default when mydomain.com is loaded?

The page requires a key code as one option to fill out the form on the page. It has some linked text that says " no key code " and then it changes the form to an address field. This is done via JavaScript.

Can I set this address option as the default when the my page loads?

This service doesn't offer the option than I want as default just yet, they will in the future but not soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not manipulate an iFramed page from a different domain via JS. This is for security reasons.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.